# List Sum same items Range

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a `List` and want to sum same values

```cs
var list = new List<DataPoint>
{
    new DataPoint(){Name = "Test",Value = 10},
    new DataPoint(){Name = "Test",Value = 10},
    new DataPoint(){Name = "Test",Value = 10},
    new DataPoint(){Name = "Test1",Value = 20},
    new DataPoint(){Name = "Test",Value = 11}
};
```

the result should be another List that look like this (sum all Names "Test", before another Names)

```cs
var result = new List<DataPoint>
{
    new DataPoint(){Name = "Test",Value = 30},
    new DataPoint(){Name = "Test1",Value = 20},
    new DataPoint(){Name = "Test",Value = 11}
};
```

how can I do that?

Comment: So the example leave some questions about other cases. If after the "Test1" entry there are multiple "Test" entries, should they also be summed together or is it just the first set of "Test" entries? And what if there are multiple "Test1" entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not a simple loop? Something like this:

```
 result = new List<DataPoint>();

 foreach (DataPoint p in list) 
   if (result.Count <= 0 || result[result.Count - 1].Name != p.Name)
     result.Add(new DataPoint() {Name = p.Name, Value = p.Value});
   else
     result[result.Count - 1].Value += p.Value;
```

Comment: @Maximilian Ast: Thank you! I'm sorry for the typo

Comment: I like how short this is while still hitting all the right points... very nice.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of solutions, one of them is: (updated)

```
var result = new List<DataPoint>();
var item = list.First();

foreach (var dataPoint in list.Skip(1))
{
    if (item.Name == dataPoint.Name)
    {
        item.Value += dataPoint.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add(item);
        item = new DataPint() { Name = dataPoint.Name, Value = dataPoint.Value };
    }
}

result.Add(item);

return result.ToList();
```

Comment: Please, check your `LINQ` solution. I think that it will not produce expected result for OP's sample.

Comment: This definately will not result in a correct answer. Note that entries with `Name = "Test"` appear multiple times in the result set (the group before and after the "Test1" entry are different groups)

Answer (score 0):

First you sum the first datapoints als long as they have the name "Test". Then you create a new list which contains a new data point with your sum. To this, you add all elements of your first list which come after your data points are called test. You can use the LINQ methods [`TakeWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=netcore-3.1) and [`SkipWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile?view=netcore-3.1) for this.

```
int sum = list.TakeWhile(x => x.Name == "Test").Sum(x => x.Value);
var firstDataPoint = new DataPoint("Test", sum);
var result = new List<DataPoint> { firstDataPoint };
result.AddRange(list.SkipWhile(x => x.Name == "Test"));
```

Comment: This solution requires mixing with outer loop if there's more than 2 categories which I would count as a downside :/

Comment: This is related to Knoop's comment to the question. Unfortunately, OP did not specify what should happen with entries named "Test" that come after another names.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this isse with a classical `foreach` loop and store the previous value to the sum if the name is eqal:

```cs
var result = new List<DataPoint>();
DataPoint sum = null;

foreach (var dp in list)
{
    if(sum == null)
    {
        // First element, so create the sum object
        sum = new DataPoint { Name = dp.Name, Value = dp.Value };
    }
    else if (sum.Name == dp.Name)
    {
        // Same as the one before, so increment the Value
        sum.Value += dp.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        // Differs from the sone before, so store the sum
        result.Add(sum);

        // Reset the sum
        sum = new DataPoint { Name = dp.Name, Value = dp.Value };
    }
}

// Add the last sum to the group
result.Add(sum);
```

Result:

> DP: {Test, 30}
> DP: {Test1, 20}
> DP: {Test, 11}

Answer (score 0):

```
var newList = new List<DataPoint>();

DataPoint working = null;
for (var x = 0; x < list.Count; x += 1) {
   var current = list[x];

   DataPoint copy() =>
      new DataPoint {
         Name = current.Name,
         Value = current.Value
      };

   if (working == null) {
      working = copy();
      continue;
   }

   if (working.Name == current.Name) {
      working.Value += current.Value;
      continue;
   }

   newList.Add(working);
   working = copy();

   var isLast = x == list.Count - 1;
   if (isLast)
      newList.Add(working);
}

foreach (var dp in newList)
   Console.WriteLine($"Name: {dp.Name}, Value: {dp.Value}");
```

Output:

```
Name: Test, Value: 30
Name: Test1, Value: 20
Name: Test, Value: 11
```